# Pass variable to stylus file from Node

Tags: node.js, stylus

How do I pass a variable from my node application to my Stylus files? For example, based on a user's locale setting that I have in Node - i.e. 'en-US', I want to pass that variable to stylus so I can reference it in my stylus files.

```
$locale = <LOCALE_VAR_FROM_NODE>

.bg-image
    background-image url('images/' + $locale + '/image.jpg')
```

Comment: Does that help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573897/node-app-variables-passed-into-stylus-file

Answer (score 0):

Try to use built-in function **use**:

**locale.js:**

```js
module.exports = function(){
  return function( style ){
    style.define('$locale', getLocale() );
  };
};
```

**style.styl:**

```
use("locale.js")

.bg-image
    background-image url('images/' + $locale + '/image.jpg')
```